# How to run async tasks synchronously (best practices)?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I've read so many posts on this, some of which are conflicting (possibly due to the age of the posts), so I just want to confirm  my understanding of "best practices" as of .NET 4.8.

For an async method that returns **Task<ResponseObject>** then we should use:

```
ResponseObject response = myAsyncTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

And for an async method that returns **Task**, then we should use:

```
var t = new Task(async () => await myAsyncTask().ConfigureAwait(false));
t.RunSynchronously();
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the first method for both, just omit the variable?

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen well, exactly.  Why would Microsoft provide multiple ways to do the same thing - it just adds to confusion.  Unless of course, there are subtle differences.

Comment: There are big differences. Don't use the `Task` constructor; that approach was never good. There's a variety of options [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

Comment: I wish Microsoft would deprecate their poor implementations and only leave the "really good ones".

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways you can combine the various building blocks and accomplish the same thing, the problem is that they are building blocks intended for different things. Deprecating/removing them to keep "the one true way" disregards all these different things and you would have a much worse situation.

Comment: Best practices, don't do it, have a sync method